# ngAnimate a DOM element that is part of a template rendered using UI Router

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have this example project that uses UI Router and template files to render DOM elements.
http://plnkr.co/edit/3KgB5g

**What I would like to achieve:** 
The headlines fading in when you click on *Population* or *Personnel* and the template is rendered and fade out when I go back to the main menu. Preferably through using a directive like so:

```
<h1 anim-fade>Population</h1>
```

**What I have tried so far:**

I tried to define CSS rules for `[ui-view].ng-enter h1` but this didn't work properly as the `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` "phases" of the view overlap so things get messy there.

I tried creating a directive with the $animate service but got stuck when it came to the decision when to fire the "enter" and "leave" events.

I'm hoping for a simple, self-contained solution and will do further research myself. In the meantime any advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I made some progress but I'm not completely satisfied yet. http://plnkr.co/edit/jehATY?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gotcha with ngAnimate is that it displays appearing and disappearing elements at the same time. You can go around this by using CSS Keyframe Animations that allows you to hide the specific element for half of the animation like so.

```
@keyframes uiview-fadeIn {
0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

49% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

50% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
}

100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
}

@keyframes uiview-fadeOut {
0% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

49% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

50% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

100% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
}
```